# Comparing files based on column

Tags: compare, awk

I try to write a script for comparing 2 large files based on column 2. Each file contains about 1 Million records. For the output, I need to know which records are common on column 2 (exist on both files) but have different value in column 1. The files are quoted comma separated value files

```
File1_pair

20151026,1111
20141113,2222
20130102,3333
77777777,9999

File2_pair
20151026,1111
20203344,2222
50506677,3333
77777777,8888

Desired_output
20141113,2222,20203344
20130102,3333,50506677
```

I tried modifying the script below but not able to get it right.

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$0]; next } !($2) in a { c++ } END { print c }' file1_pair file2_pair`
```

Comment: Are the values in the second column **exactly** common between the two files? In the same order and both have the same value on every line?

Comment: no, value in column 2 from both the files can be different and not is same order.

Comment: But the values in column two are at least unique?

Comment: yes, the value in column 2 are always unique in the same file

Comment: Lines with values in column 2 that don't match are ignored entirely? Or does the value of column 2 matching between the files on a given line not matter? (That is why are `77777777,8888` and `77777777,9999` not in the output?)

Comment: Yes, if column 2 does not match, it should be ignored entirely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea you were just operating on the wrong fields.

You need to save all the `$2` values from the first file in the array and then check the `$2` values from the second file against that array. You also need to compare the value of `$1` in the corresponding rows.

This awk script will do that.

```
awk -F , -v OFS=, '
    NR==FNR {
        # Store the value of $1 under the $2 key in a
        a[$2]=$1
        next
    }
    # If $2 is in a (we've seen this value before) and
    # if the value in the array (first file's $1 value) doesn't match this files $1 value
    ($2 in a) && (a[$2] != $1) {
        # Print the original $1 value (from the array),$2,$1
        print a[$2],$2,$1
    }' file1_pair file2_pair
```

Comment: @Jimbo if it worked to you, remember you can accept the answer.

Comment: @fedorqui, thanks for the reminder. Still new to this community.